# How can I calculate if three different coordinates are adjacent to each other on a grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates

I am using C# to make a linker game, where the player has a grid of different coloured cells and links ones of the same colour vertically, horizontally or diagonally. At the moment, I am using a 5x5 grid. The bottom left coordinate is (0,0) and the top right is (4,4).

I am trying to detect a deadlocked board, so when there are not at least three cells of one colour linkable, but am really struggling to implement the logic.

I am getting a list of all cells of a certain colour and I want to write a function to check the coordinates of these cells to see if three are next to each other.

For example, let's say I have the following board with the following blue cells (circles are the blues):

```
x x x x x
x x x o o
x x x o x
o x x x x
o x x o o
```

I scan the board from left to right, bottom to top, I pass in:

```
0,0
3,0
4,0
0,1
3,2
3,3
4,3
```

From this, I know (3,2) can connect to (3,3) as it is above it. I then know (3,3) can connect to (4,3) as it is to the right of it.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can write a function to iterate over these coordinates and check for neighbouring ones? With a view to returning true or false if three of them are connectable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a list of groups of connecting tiles. One of the ways to achieve this is to use a recursive function.

A bit of pseudocode:

```
void function addAdjacentTiles(List knownTiles, Tile currentTile):
    append currentTile to knownTiles
    for each tile adjacent to currentTile:
        if adjacentTile is the same colour and is not in knownTiles:
            addAdjacentTiles(adjacentTile) // This is the recursive part


listOfGroups = empty list

for each tile:
    if (tile is not in listOfGroups):
        tileGroup = empty list
        addAdjacentTiles(tileGroup, tile)
        append tileGroup to listOfGroups

longest = max(the sizes of all groups)
```

Note that the addAdjacentTiles function doesn't have to return anything, as it modifies the knownTiles variable which is mutable.